# Using a macro to initialize a big array of non-Copy elements

Tags: rust, initializer-list, static-initializer

I'm trying to initialize a big array of elements with the same initializer. 64 elements is just an example — I want to make it at least 16k. Unfortunately a simple

```
let array : [AllocatedMemory<u8>; 64] = [AllocatedMemory::<u8>{mem:&mut []};64];
```

won't work because the `AllocatedMemory` struct does not implement `Copy`

```
error: the trait `core::marker::Copy` is not implemented for the type `AllocatedMemory<'_, u8>` [E0277]
let array : [AllocatedMemory<u8>; 64] = [AllocatedMemory::<u8>{mem:&mut []}; 64];
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So I tried macros to no avail:

```
struct AllocatedMemory<'a, T: 'a> {
    mem: &'a mut [T],
}

macro_rules! init_memory_helper {
    (1, $T : ty) => { AllocatedMemory::<$T>{mem: &mut []} };
    (2, $T : ty) => { init_memory_helper!(1, $T), init_memory_helper!(1, $T) };
    (4, $T : ty) => { init_memory_helper!(2, $T), init_memory_helper!(2, $T) };
    (8, $T : ty) => { init_memory_helper!(4, $T), init_memory_helper!(4, $T) };
    (16, $T : ty) => { init_memory_helper!(8, $T), init_memory_helper!(8, $T) };
    (32, $T : ty) => { init_memory_helper!(16, $T), init_memory_helper!(16, $T) };
    (64, $T : ty) => { init_memory_helper!(32, $T), init_memory_helper!(32, $T) };
}

macro_rules! init_memory {
    (1, $T : ty) => { [init_memory_helper!(1, $T)] };
    (2, $T : ty) => { [init_memory_helper!(2, $T)] };
    (4, $T : ty) => { [init_memory_helper!(4, $T)] };
    (8, $T : ty) => { [init_memory_helper!(8, $T)] };
    (16, $T : ty) => { [init_memory_helper!(16, $T)] };
    (32, $T : ty) => { [init_memory_helper!(32, $T)] };
    (64, $T : ty) => { [init_memory_helper!(64, $T)] };
}

fn main() {
    let array: [AllocatedMemory<u8>; 64] = init_memory!(64, u8);
    println!("{:?}", array[0].mem.len());
}
```

The error message is

```
error: macro expansion ignores token `,` and any following
    (64, $T : ty) => { init_memory_helper!(32, $T), init_memory_helper!(32, $T) };
note: caused by the macro expansion here; the usage of `init_memory_helper!` is likely invalid in expression context
```

Is there any way to initialize this array without cut and pasting every initializer?

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to count with macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751796/is-there-a-way-to-count-with-macros), tl;dr -> not with regular macros.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that [the expansion of a macro absolutely *must* be a complete and independently valid grammar element](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/mbe-syn-expansion.html).  You can't expand to `a, b` any more than you can expand to `42 +`.  There is also no way to (statically) concatenate or cons arrays in Rust; the entire array initialiser must be expanded to in *one* step.

This can be done using macros with [push-down accumulation](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/pat-push-down-accumulation.html).  The trick is that you pass the not-yet-syntactically-valid partial array expression *down* the recursion, instead of constructing on the way back out.  When you reach the bottom of the expansion, you emit the now complete expression all at once.

Here's a macro that supports arrays of length 0 through 8, and powers of 2 up to 64:

```rust
macro_rules! array {
    (@accum (0, $($_es:expr),*) -> ($($body:tt)*))
        => {array!(@as_expr [$($body)*])};
    (@accum (1, $($es:expr),*) -> ($($body:tt)*))
        => {array!(@accum (0, $($es),*) -> ($($body)* $($es,)*))};
    (@accum (2, $($es:expr),*) -> ($($body:tt)*))
        => {array!(@accum (0, $($es),*) -> ($($body)* $($es,)* $($es,)*))};
    (@accum (3, $($es:expr),*) -> ($($body:tt)*))
        => {array!(@accum (2, $($es),*) -> ($($body)* $($es,)*))};
    (@accum (4, $($es:expr),*) -> ($($body:tt)*))
        => {array!(@accum (2, $($es,)* $($es),*) -> ($($body)*))};
    (@accum (5, $($es:expr),*) -> ($($body:tt)*))
        => {array!(@accum (4, $($es),*) -> ($($body)* $($es,)*))};
    (@accum (6, $($es:expr),*) -> ($($body:tt)*))
        => {array!(@accum (4, $($es),*) -> ($($body)* $($es,)* $($es,)*))};
    (@accum (7, $($es:expr),*) -> ($($body:tt)*))
        => {array!(@accum (4, $($es),*) -> ($($body)* $($es,)* $($es,)* $($es,)*))};
    (@accum (8, $($es:expr),*) -> ($($body:tt)*))
        => {array!(@accum (4, $($es,)* $($es),*) -> ($($body)*))};
    (@accum (16, $($es:expr),*) -> ($($body:tt)*))
        => {array!(@accum (8, $($es,)* $($es),*) -> ($($body)*))};
    (@accum (32, $($es:expr),*) -> ($($body:tt)*))
        => {array!(@accum (16, $($es,)* $($es),*) -> ($($body)*))};
    (@accum (64, $($es:expr),*) -> ($($body:tt)*))
        => {array!(@accum (32, $($es,)* $($es),*) -> ($($body)*))};

    (@as_expr $e:expr) => {$e};

    [$e:expr; $n:tt] => { array!(@accum ($n, $e) -> ()) };
}

fn main() {
    let ones: [i32; 64] = array![1; 64];
    println!("{:?}", &ones[..]);
}
```

The strategy here is to multiply the size of the input on powers of two, and add the remainder for non-powers of two.  This is to stave off the macro recursion limit (I believe the default is 64) by making sure `$n` drops in value quickly.

Just to forestall the frequent follow-up question: *no*, you can't simplify this with arithmetic; you can't *do* arithmetic in macros.  :)

**Addendum**: If you're not sure how this works, you can pass `-Z trace-macros` to `rustc` when compiling and see each macro invocation that gets expanded.  Using `array![1; 6]` as an example, you get something like this:

```
array! { 1 ; 6 }
array! { @ accum ( 6 , 1 ) -> (  ) }
array! { @ accum ( 4 , 1 ) -> ( 1 , 1 , ) }
array! { @ accum ( 2 , 1 , 1 ) -> ( 1 , 1 , ) }
array! { @ accum ( 0 , 1 , 1 ) -> ( 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , ) }
array! { @ as_expr [ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , ] }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with these macros is that the former one does not produce valid syntactic forms in Rust - two expressions combined by a comma is not a valid form by itself. The fact that it is "injected" into square brackets in another macro is irrelevant.

Frankly, I don't know how to do it properly with regular arrays. Absence of numbers as generic parameters is a well-known problem which precludes lots of useful patterns. If they were supported, for example, it would be possible to have a function like this one:

```
fn make_array<T, N: usize, F>(f: F) -> [T; N] where F: FnMut() -> T
```

which creates an array of arbitrary size, filling it with the result of function invocation:

```
let array: [_; 64] = make_array(|| AllocatedMemory::<u8>{ mem: &mut [] })
```

But alas, no such thing is available in Rust yet. You have to use dynamic structures like `Vec` instead. You can also try [arrayvec](https://crates.io/crates/arrayvec), which provides a `Vec`-like API for some fixed-size arrays; using it you can do something like this:

```
use arrayvec::ArrayVec; // 0.5.1

fn main() {
    let mut array = ArrayVec::<[_; 64]>::new();
    for _ in 0..array.len() {
        array.push(AllocatedMemory::<u8> { mem: &mut [] });
    }
    let array = array.into_inner(); // array: [AllocatedMemory<u8>; 64]
}
```

See also:

- [How do I collect into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26757355/155423)

Comment: That's a really cool lib--unfortunately I did forget to mention that I want to refrain from unsafe territory, especially for 3rd party code

Comment: I actually only need a list interface...I wonder if I could use a few macros to generate a list of size N maybe some sort of intrusive thing with an Option next

Comment: @hellcatv if you use std library even in the slightest, you will depend on unsafe code. Almost all useful abstractions (collections, memory management, I/O, threading, etc.) are based on unsafe code and can't really be done without it. There is nothing wrong in using safe interfaces around unsafe internals. You don't have to use `unsafe` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A ["safe" implementation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=bafb8c439b849f60d67665ca9e146b5f) which runs on stable, heavily inspired by [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/29ymbx/a_macro_to_fill_a_fixed_length_array/):

```
// #![feature(core_intrinsics)]
// use std::ptr;
use std::mem;
use std::mem::MaybeUninit;

type MyStructValue = Vec<usize>;
type UsizeToVecBuilder = Box<dyn Fn(usize) -> Vec<usize>>;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    value: MyStructValue,
}

macro_rules! make_array {
    ([$t:ident; $n:expr], $constructor:expr, $builder:expr) => {{
        let mut data: [MaybeUninit<$t>; $n] = unsafe { MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init() };

        let mut i: usize = 0;
        for elem in &mut data[..] {
            *elem = MaybeUninit::new($constructor(i, $builder));
            i += 1;
        }

        unsafe { mem::transmute::<_, [$t; $n]>(data) }
    }};
}

fn main() {
    println!(
        "{:?}",
        make_array!(
            [MyStruct; 5],
            |i, b: UsizeToVecBuilder| MyStruct { value: b(i) },
            Box::new(|i| (0..i + 1).collect())
        )
    );
}

// unstable version: (see reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/29ymbx/a_macro_to_fill_a_fixed_length_array/)
//
// macro_rules! make_array {
//     ($n:expr, $constructor:expr) => {{
//         let mut items: [_; $n] = unsafe { mem::uninitialized() };
//         for i in 0..$n {
//             let val = $constructor(i);
//             unsafe {
//                 std::intrinsics::volatile_copy_nonoverlapping_memory(
//                     &mut items[i], &val, 1
//                 );
//                 // ptr::copy_nonoverlapping_memory(&mut items[i], &val, 1);
//                 mem::forget(val);
//             }
//         }
//         items
//     }}
// }

// fn main() {
// unstable version:
// println!("{:?}", make_array!(5, |i| MyStruct { value: i }));
// }
```

Comment: See also [What is the proper way to initialize a fixed length array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31361031/155423)

Comment: I would recommend that most people do **not** use this answer. `ArrayVec`, as shown in [Vladimir Matveev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36258710/155423), does the unsafe code under the hood and provides a nicer API.