# Is it possible to write a macro that expands an expression N times? (Where N is a constant)

Tags: macros, rust

Say we need to declare a fixed size array with values, where the size of the array is defined by a constant that may change depending on compile time settings.

So for example:

`let my_array = expand_into_array!(j, ARRAY_SIZE, -v0[j] * f);`

Where `ARRAY_SIZE` is a constant, for example:
`const ARRAY_SIZE: usize = 3;`

Could expand into something like...

```
let my_array = [
    {let j = 0; {-v0[j] * f}},
    {let j = 1; {-v0[j] * f}},
    {let j = 2; {-v0[j] * f}},
];
```

Since the expression is a fixed size array, it may be possible to use pattern matching, for a limited number of items ... up to 32 for example.

Is it possible to write a macro that expands an expression *N* times, based on a constant integer?

---

*Details...*

Looking into this, I wrote a macro which defines an array, then fills it in, eg:

```
const ARRAY_SIZE: usize = 3;

macro_rules! expand_into_array {
    ($index_var:ident, $const_size:expr, $body:expr) => {
        {
            let mut tmp: [_; $const_size] = [0.0; $const_size];
            for $index_var in 0..$const_size {
                tmp[$index_var] = $body;
            }
            // TODO, check $body _never_ breaks.
            tmp
        }
    }
}

pub fn negated_array(v0: &[f64; ARRAY_SIZE]) -> [f64; ARRAY_SIZE] {
    expand_into_array!(j, ARRAY_SIZE, {
        -v0[j]
    })
}
```

This works as expected, and besides the wrinkle (that the `$body` expression could include a `break`). this works without problems.

However initializing the array to 0.0 isn't getting optimized out (changing this value shows up as changes when run with:
 `cargo rustc --release -- --emit asm`

I'd rather not use `unsafe { std::mem::uninitialized }`.

---

Update, from asking [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751796), it seems macros can only match against literals, and *not* constants.

So this is simply not possible with macros in Rust.

Comment: This question is asking about using constants to declare arrays, the other question is dealing with dynamic vectors. While they're related, I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: @ker: I think that this is actually a *reverse* of the question you linked. Counting repetitions is tricky, but doable, here however the question is about *generating* repetitions when there are none in the input (just a literal number).

Comment: The [implementation of `Default` for primitive arrays](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libcore/array.rs#L221) is close (up to a fixed length).  You might be able to replace the sequence of `T`s in the macro call with a clever expression which lets you pass the index in.

Comment: Read all 3 questions marked as duplicate, and they all seem only *slightly* related. While its not useful to have every variation of a question, is it necessary to be so zealous marking duplicates here? Also, the other questions seem quite a bit more advanced then this one.

Comment: @ideasman42: The first one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751796/is-there-a-way-to-count-with-macros) is actually spot on, although simpler.

Comment: @MatthieuM. this matches against a literal, not a constant *(noted in the title and the example)*. From checking on this further it seems this is the reason attempting to follow similar methods to the answers given failed.

Comment: @ideasman42: Oh sorry, I am afraid that it was so clear to everyone that using macros necessarily meant using a literals (since they do not evaluate values, only reason in tokens) that we took for granted that the actual issue was in the generation of repetitions. Since you opened a new question specifically on the constant/literal distinction though I would say it does not matter.

Comment: Since this question is not a duplicate, could the duplicate mark be removed?