# How to create a macro to create an array of structs?

Tags: macros, rust

Given a `struct` `Foo`:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    info: &'a str
}
```

To create an `array` of `Foo`s with different strings inside, I would like to have a macro, which could be used like:

```
assert_eq!(make_foo!("test"; 2), [Foo { info: "test 1" }, Foo { info: "test 2" }]);
```

What I am confused about specifically is how to iterate over the specific number of times as specified in the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, to the best of my knowledge, **it's impossible** to create a macro which works *exactly* as you wish. It's only *kind of* possible. I'll explain:

- First, there is [no way to count with macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751796/is-there-a-way-to-count-with-macros), so you can't do the "repeat this n-times" on your own. This is the reason why you can't generate the strings `"test 1"`, `"test 2"` and so on. It's just **not possible**. You can, however, create an array of structs with only `"test"` as string by using the standard array initializer `[val; n]`.
- Second, in order to use the array initializer, the type inside the array has to be `Copy`. But in your case that's not a big problem, since your struct can just derive it.

---

So let's see, what we can do ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5db14d8160e637244a93dd9e8f4ede9c&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct Foo<'a> {
    info: &'a str
}

macro_rules! make_foo {
    ($info:expr; $num:expr) => {
        [Foo { info: $info }; $num]
    }
}
```

First, we need to derive a few traits for your struct:

- `Copy`, see above
- `Clone` is required by `Copy`
- `PartialEq` and `Debug` are required by `assert_eq!()`

I think the macro itself is fairly easy to understand: it's just using the array initializer internally.

---

> **But how to get exactly the behavior asked in the question?**

Don't use a macro and don't use fixed size arrays. A normal function and `Vec<T>` is probably fine. You *could*, of course, also write a compiler plugin, but those are unstable right now and it's probably not worth the hassle anyway.