# Is it possible to have a recursive function computed at compile-time in Rust?

Tags: recursion, macros, rust, constants, compile-time-constant

I want to compute the factorial of a `const`:

```rust
const N: usize = 4;
const N_PERMUTATIONS = factorial(N);
```

The solutions I've thought of that don't work in Rust 1.18 are:

- `const fn` — conditional statements are not allowed (or at least not implemented) in `const fn`, so neither of these will compile:

  ```
  const fn factorial(n: usize) -> usize {
      match n {
          0 => 1,
          _ => n * factorial(n-1)
      }
  }
  ```

  ```rust
  const fn factorial(n: usize) -> usize {
      if n == 0 {
          1
      } else {
          n * factorial(n-1)
      }
  }
  ```
- macros — evaluation of expressions is performed after all macro expansion.  This macro will never reach the base case, since after four iterations the argument is `4-1-1-1-1`, which is not matched by `0`:

  ```rust
  macro_rules!factorial {
      (0) => (1);
      ($n:expr) => ($n * factorial($n-1));
  }
  ```

I also tried the following, which would work if `*` had short-circuit evaluation, but as-is has unconditional recursion which yields a stack overflow:

```rust
const fn factorial(n: usize) -> usize {
    ((n == 0) as usize) + ((n != 0) as usize) * n * factorial(n-1)
}
```

As Matthieu M. pointed out, we can avoid integer underflow (but not stack overflow) by using `factorial(n - ((n != 0) as usize))`.

For now I've resorted to manually computing the factorial.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from utilizing a build script?

Comment: See also [Is there a way to count with macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33751796/155423)

Comment: You could perhaps manually compute it but write a test that asserts the dynamic computation?

Comment: The recursion here is unconditional, since you *always* call `factorial`. Multiplying `n` and `1` in `factorial(n - 1)` leads to a stackoverflow of the compiler => https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a5225a8d24f6857c75f85e843f1f3c11&version=nightly&backtrace=0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to count with macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751796/is-there-a-way-to-count-with-macros)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your original question, Rust has been updated and now supports conditionals in `const fn`, so the first two solutions work. See the [Const functions section in the Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/functions.html#const-functions)
which states that you can have "Calls to other safe const functions (whether by function call or method call)" in const functions.

For your particular factorial example, you have (at least) a couple options. Here is a factorial function that I have successfully compiled:

```rust
const fn factorial(n: u64) -> u64 {
    match n {
        0u64 | 1u64 => 1,
        2u64..=20u64 => factorial(n - 1u64) * n,
        _ => 0,
    }
}
```

Note, n! where n > 20 will overflow a `u64`, so I decided to return 0 in that case. Also, since `usize` could be a 32-bit value, I explicitly use the 64-bit `u64` in this case. Handling the `u64` overflow case also prevents the stack overflow. This could return an `Option<u64>` instead:

```rust
const fn factorial(n: u64) -> Option<u64> {
    match n {
        0u64 | 1u64 => Some(1),
        2u64..=20u64 => match factorial(n - 1u64) {
            Some(x) => Some(n * x),
            None => None,
        },
        _ => None,
    }
}
```

In my case, returning an `Option<u64>` limited how I could use the function, so I found it more useful to just return a `u64` with 0 as the analogue to `None`.

Answer (score 3):

This is currently explored under the feature `const_fn`, but for now you cannot call a function, even const, from another const function.

You can however break out the big guns: metaprogramming (procedural macro) to compute the value at compile-time. I found [this crate](https://docs.rs/const_fn) for example (but did not test it, though).

[This Rosetta Code page on compile time calculation](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Compile-time_calculation#Rust) shows that the compiler can do *some* compile-time optimization, but nothing is guaranteed, and this is only a particular case.

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT with const initialization]

It is also possible to compute factorial by using rust type system. Crate typenum allows that by recoding binary arithmetic on the basis of the type system:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d34eef48622363ca2096a246cd933554

```
use std::ops::{ Mul, Sub, };
use typenum::{
    B1, Sub1, Prod, U0, U1, U2, U3, U4, U5, U20, U24, Unsigned, Bit, UInt
};

trait Fact {
    type F: Unsigned;
}

impl Fact for U0 {
    type F = U1;
}

impl<U: Unsigned, B: Bit> Fact for UInt<U, B> where UInt<U, B>: Sub<B1>, 
        Sub1<UInt<U, B>>: Fact, UInt<U, B> : Mul<<Sub1<UInt<U, B>> as Fact>::F>,
        Prod<UInt<U, B>,<Sub1<UInt<U, B>> as Fact>::F>: Unsigned {
    type F = Prod<UInt<U, B>,<Sub1<UInt<U, B>> as Fact>::F>;
}

fn main() {
    type F0 = <U0 as Fact>::F;
    type F1 = <U1 as Fact>::F;
    type F2 = <U2 as Fact>::F;
    type F3 = <U3 as Fact>::F;
    type F4 = <U4 as Fact>::F;
    type F5 = <U5 as Fact>::F;
    type F20 = <U20 as Fact>::F;
    const FACT0: usize = F0::USIZE;
    const FACT1: usize = F1::USIZE;
    const FACT2: usize = F2::USIZE;
    const FACT3: usize = F3::USIZE;
    const FACT4: usize = F4::USIZE;
    const FACT5: usize = F5::USIZE;
    const FACT20: usize = F20::USIZE;
    println!("0! = {}", FACT0);
    println!("1! = {}", FACT1);
    println!("2! = {}", FACT2);
    println!("3! = {}", FACT3);
    println!("4! = {}", FACT4);
    println!("5! = {}", FACT5);
    println!("20! = {}\n", FACT20);
    println!("Binary structure:");
    println!("F4 = {:?}",F4::new());
    println!("U24 = {:?}\n",U24::new());

    fn print_u24(_: U24) {
        println!("type F4 is the same as type U24");
    }
    print_u24(F4::new());
}
```

which results in:

```
0! = 1
1! = 1
2! = 2
3! = 6
4! = 24
5! = 120
20! = 2432902008176640000

Binary structure:
F4 = UInt { msb: UInt { msb: UInt { msb: UInt { msb: UInt { msb: UTerm, lsb: B1 }, lsb: B1 }, lsb: B0 }, lsb: B0 }, lsb: B0 }
U24 = UInt { msb: UInt { msb: UInt { msb: UInt { msb: UInt { msb: UTerm, lsb: B1 }, lsb: B1 }, lsb: B0 }, lsb: B0 }, lsb: B0 }

type F4 is the same as type U24
```

The factorial types F0, F1, F2, F3 F4 F5, F20, are of course generated at compile time.
Constant USIZE associated with trait Unsigned is then used to initialize usize constants, FACT0, FACT1, ...

Well, this is certainly not the most efficient way to compute a factorial at compilation time; const fn is better! However, it is interesting to see that rust typing system is sufficiently powerful to implement some functional and recursive computation at compile time!

This may be useful for other tasks. For example, it is also an interesting alternative to const generics when you have to deal with some arithmetic on it (at least for now). Typically, such typing mechanism are used in generic-array or in nalgebra.