# How can I use #[derive] on a type containing an array where the length is specified by a macro?

Tags: macros, rust

I have this code:

```
macro_rules! count {
    () => { 1 };
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct<T> {
    field_list: [T; count!()],
}
```

The compiler gives this error:

```
error: `derive` cannot be used on items with type macros
 --> src/main.rs:7:21
  |
7 |     field_list: [T; count!()],
  |                     ^^^^^^^^
```

Is there any way to use `#[derive]` on a type containing an array where the length is specified by a macro?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to count with macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751796/is-there-a-way-to-count-with-macros)

Comment: @Stargateur No, these problems are totally different.

Comment: I do not think this is a duplicate of "Is there a way to count with macros?" The code has already solved how to count (for some form of counting), but the problem occurs after that.

Comment: What is also strange is that the same code works if the generic type is replaced with a concrete one, such as `i32`.

Comment: @ZzTux well, your very first question was "How to specify array size by macro in Rust?", but I let the link it's maybe just related.

Comment: @Shepmaster [It works on non-generic type as you said.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=49f0c890c0fc8998f2985174990db9ee&version=stable&mode=debug) Maybe this is a compiler bug? Should I open an issue on Github?

Comment: @Shepmaster It seems to fail when the struct is generic, even if the array element type is concrete. [You don't even need arrays.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b058f3b36f5a8b070857b873c0840543&version=stable&mode=debug)

Comment: I opened an issue on Github: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50676

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting my answer from the Github issue:

> It is intentional (here is the [historical
>   record](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/33769)), but there is a
>   possibility the situation could be improved in the future, and at
>   least the error message should be rewritten to explain why it refuses
>   to compile.
>
> The underlying issue is that `#[derive]` macros need to "forward"
>   their trait requirements to all the fields of the struct. For
>   `MyStruct` to be `Debug`, the type of `field` must also be `Debug`.
>   Consider this one:
>
> ```
> #[derive(Debug)] struct MyStruct<T: FromStr> {
>     field: T
> }
> ```
>
> We need to generate `impl<T: FromStr> Debug for MyStruct<T> where T:
>   Debug { ... }` (you'll see why I picked
>   [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) in a
>   second). However in this case:
>
> ```
> #[derive(Debug)] struct MyStruct<T> {
>     field: T::Err
> }
> ```
>
> Here the field is an associated type, so the generated code actually
>   needs to be `impl<T: FromStr> Debug for MyStruct<T> where T::Err:
>   Debug { ... }`.
>
> The derive macros actually scan the field types to see whether they
>   need to bound `T` or an associated type. But if you use a type macro,
>   this breaks. The code generation can't see through the macro, so it
>   doesn't know what bounds to generate.
>
> When this was discovered we couldn't decide whether to let the type
>   macro be expanded eagerly (seems like you could get into a loop or
>   ordering issues), just copy the macro into the `where` clause (derives
>   normally don't do this because it could expand to a private type,
>   causing type errors in generated code), or [something
>   else](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1671), so we punted and
>   made it an error.

The problem can't really be fixed while obeying the "policies" of deriving: (1) it generates the bounds for you, and (2) it only generates code that compiles. But since custom derive is stable, there are crates you can use, like [derivative](https://crates.io/crates/derivative), that sidestep the problem by letting you rewrite the bound:

```
#[derive(Derivative)]
#[derivative(Debug)]
struct MyStruct<T> {
    #[derivative(Debug(bound="T: ::std::fmt::Debug"))]
    field_list: [T; count!()],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be to use two macros, one macro that defines the struct and another macro that defines the size.

```
macro_rules! foo {
    ($x:expr) => {
        #[derive(Debug)]
        struct MyStruct<T> {
            field_list: [T; $x],
        }
    };
}

macro_rules! bar {
    () => {
        foo!(1);
    };
}

bar!();
```

---

> [It works on non-generic type as you said.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=49f0c890c0fc8998f2985174990db9ee&version=stable&mode=debug) Maybe this is a compiler bug? Should I open an issue on Github?

This is probably not a bug, but certainly a limitation of macros. You could however open an issue to ask to improve it.

Comment: This doesn't work if I replace foo!(1) with foo!(my_macro!()).