# Recursive macro makes infinite recursion

Tags: recursion, macros, rust, rust-cargo

I made a simple macro that returns the taken parameter.

```
macro_rules! n {
    ($n:expr) => {{
        let val: usize = $n;
        match val {
            0 => 0,
            _ => n!(val - 1),
        }
    }};
}
```

When I compile this code with the option `external-macro-backtrace`, it raises an error:

```
error: recursion limit reached while expanding the macro `n`
  --> src/main.rs:15:18
   |
10 |   macro_rules! n {
   |  _-
   | |_|
   | |
11 | |     ($n:expr) => {{
12 | |         let val: usize = $n;
13 | |         match val {
14 | |             0 => 0,
15 | |             _ => n!(val - 1),
   | |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
   | |                  |
   | |                  in this macro invocation
16 | |         }
17 | |     }};
18 | | }
   | | -
   | |_|
   | |_in this expansion of `n!`
   |   in this expansion of `n!`
...
31 | |     n!(1);
   | |     ------ in this macro invocation
   |
   = help: consider adding a `#![recursion_limit="128"]` attribute to your crate
```

I changed the `recursion_limit` to 128 and higher, but the compiler error message just increase as well. Even when I call `n!(0)` it makes the same error. I think it is infinite recursion, but I can't find the reason.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Is there a way to count with macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33751796/155423).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it really is an infinite recursion. Check what your macro invocation `n!(0)` will be expanded into:

```
{
    let val: usize = 0;
    match val {
        0 => 0,
        _ => n!(0 - 1),
    }
}
```

...and since there's no way for argument of `n!` to stop growing negative, it'll repeat (with `n!(0 - 1 - 1)` in the second match arm, then `n!(0 - 1 - 1 - 1)` etc.) infinitely.

The key point here is that the macro expansion happens in compile-time, while the `match` statement you're trying to use to limit the recursion is invoked only at run-time and can't stop anything from appear before that. Unhappily, there's no easy way to do this, since Rust won't evaluate macro arguments (even if it's a constant expression), and so just adding the `(0) => {0}` branch to the macro won't work, since the macro will be invoked as (for example) `n!(1 - 1)`.