# Using rust macros to procedurally call functions

Tags: rust, macros, metaprogramming

Can i do something like

```rust
macro_rules! problem_call {
    ($x:expr) => {
        problem_x();
    }
}
```

So i can call a series of functions that have names like: (problem_1, problem_2, problem_3, ...)

with a variable like: problem_call(2) or maybe problem_call('2')

(This code obviously doesn't work, but is there any way to reproduce something like that?)

Comment: I think it's only possible with procedural macro or build script ofc. You can't count or do anything like that in declarative macro thus the name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to count with macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751796/is-there-a-way-to-count-with-macros)

Comment: I'm unsure I understand your requirement can you give more example or clarify the question somehow ?

Comment: Not exacly, but i think a procedural macro solve my question. I ll read more about, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible using `concat_idents` in Rust Nightly.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.concat_idents.html

This should be something like what you're looking for:

```rust
#![feature(concat_idents)]

macro_rules! problem_call {
    ($x:ident) => {
        concat_idents!(problem_, $x)();
    }
}

fn problem_abc() {
    println!("abc");
}

problem_call!(abc);
```