# Counting length of repetition in macro

Tags: macros, rust

I'm trying to implement a macro to allow MATLAB-esque matrix creation. I've got a basic working macro but I still have a long way to go.

I want to be able to enforce the right structure (same number of elements in each row) but I'm not sure how to do this within the macro. I think I want to enforce that each internal repetition has the same length - is this something I can do?

Here is my code so far:

```
pub struct Matrix<T> {
    pub cols: usize,
    pub rows: usize,
    pub data: Vec<T>
}

macro_rules! mat {
    ( $($( $x:expr ),*);* ) => {
        {
            let mut vec = Vec::new();
            let mut rows = 0;

            $(
                $(
                    vec.push($x);
                )*
                rows += 1;
            )*
            Matrix { cols : vec.len()/rows, rows: rows, data: vec}
        }
    };
}
```

[It works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=946214bff9b15f5cec6a&version=stable) but as you can see isn't very safe. It has no restrictions on the structure.

I want to do a lot more with this macro but I think this is a good start!

**Update:**

Here is [some playground code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9347cae85fe9d845d666&version=stable) for a crappy implementation I worked out. If anyone has any better suggestions please let me know! Otherwise I'll close this myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create a macro which counts the number of expanded items?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30152800/is-it-possible-to-create-a-macro-which-counts-the-number-of-expanded-items)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, to quickly address the title of your question: see the [Counting chapter in The Little Book of Rust Macros](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/blk-counting.html).  To summarise: there is no direct way, you need to write a macro that expands to something you can count in regular code.

Now, to address your *actual* question: hoo boy.

It's not so much *counting* that you want, it's to fail at compile time if the sub-sequences have different lengths.

First of all, there's no *clean* way to trigger a compilation failure from a macro.  You can trigger some *other* pre-existing error, but you can't control the actual error message.

Secondly, there's no easy way to do "variable" comparisons in macros *at all*.  You can *sometimes* compare against a fixed token sequence, but you're not doing that here.

So it's *doubly* not-really-doable.

The simplest thing to do is check the lengths during construction at runtime, and return an error or panic if they don't match.

---

Is it *actually* impossible?  I don't believe so.  If you're willing to accept inscrutable error messages and a *massive* jump in complexity, you can check for length equality between two token sequences like so:

```
macro_rules! tts_equal_len {
    (($_lhs:tt $($lhs_tail:tt)*), ($_rhs:tt $($rhs_tail:tt)*)) => {
        tts_equal_len!(($($lhs_tail)*), ($($rhs_tail)*))
    };
    (($($_lhs_tail:tt)+), ()) => { do_something_bad!() };
    ((), ($($_rhs_tail:tt)+)) => { do_something_bad!() };
    ((), ()) => { do_something_good!() };
}

macro_rules! do_something_bad { () => { { println!("kaboom!") } } }
macro_rules! do_something_good { () => { { println!("no kaboom!") } } }

fn main() {
    tts_equal_len!((,,,), (,,,));
    tts_equal_len!((,,,), (,,));
    tts_equal_len!((,), (,,));
}
```

Again, the real problem is finding some way to fail at compile time such that the user will understand *why* compilation failed.

Comment: I was worried this might be the case. Thanks for your implementation - I have no idea how it works but I'll figure it out!

Maybe it's easier in this case to write a compiler plugin? I haven't looked at them yet but from what I've read this is a decent use case?

Comment: @user124784: You could do that, but keep in mind that compiler plugins are unstable, break frequently, and cannot be used on anything other than nightly compiler builds.

Comment: As of Rust 1.20 (August 2017) the [`compile_error!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.compile_error.html) macro is available which allows you to fail at compile time with a user-readable error message. This makes the `tts_equal_len` macro proposed here much more readable for the end user and avoids needing to insert intentionally bad code to fail compilation when the tts aren't the same.

Answer (score 9):

```
macro_rules! count {
    () => (0usize);
    ( $x:tt $($xs:tt)* ) => (1usize + count!($($xs)*));
}

macro_rules! mat {
    ( $( $x:expr ),* ) => { {
        let vec = vec![$($x),*];
        Matrix { cols : vec.len(), rows: 1, data: vec }
    } };
    ( $( $x0:expr ),* ; $($( $x:expr ),*);* ) => { {
        let mut _assert_width0 = [(); count!($($x0)*)];
        let mut vec = Vec::new();
        let rows = 1usize;
        let cols = count!($($x0)*);

        $( vec.push($x0); )*

        $(
            let rows = rows + 1usize;
            let _assert_width = [(); count!($($x)*)];
            _assert_width0 = _assert_width;
            $( vec.push($x); )*
        )*

        Matrix { cols : cols, rows: rows, data: vec }
    } }
}
```

[playground](http://is.gd/173rwm)

The `count!` macro expands to a constant expression that represents the number of arguments it got as input. It's just a helper for the `mat!` macro. If you need to count a lot of items and the compiler can't cope with it, see [the Counting chapter in The Little Book of Rust Macros](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/blk-counting.html), which has more complex macros for counting.

My version of the macro uses dummy variables and assignments to verify that the width of all rows are the same. First off, I changed the macro's pattern to handle the first row separately from the subsequent rows. The first variable, `_assert_width0`, is initialized with an array of units (`()`, which makes the array take no memory), with the size of the array being the number of items in the first row. Then, `_assert_width` is also initialized with an array of units, with the size of the array being the number of items in each subsequent row. Then, `_assert_width` is assigned to `_assert_width0`. The magic here is that this line will raise a compiler error if the width of a row doesn't match the width of the first row, since the types of the array won't match (you might have e.g. `[(); 3]` and `[(); 4]`). The error isn't super clear if you don't know what's going on in the macro, though:

```
<anon>:38:24: 38:37 error: mismatched types:
 expected `[(); 3]`,
    found `[(); 4]`
(expected an array with a fixed size of 3 elements,
    found one with 4 elements) [E0308]
<anon>:38           _assert_width0 = _assert_width;
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:47:13: 47:44 note: in this expansion of mat! (defined in <anon>)
<anon>:38:24: 38:37 help: see the detailed explanation for E0308
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is a really smart answer but it does create an issue - the user can't create a single row matrix. Is that something which can be fixed? Can we make the repeated rows optional?

Comment: You should replace `0` and `1` in `count!` with `0usize` and `1usize`, or you'll *rapidly* hit exponential compile time problems due to integer inference.  Also, this definition of `count!` is only good up to about 64 elements; the link in my answer has more robust definitions.  Having said that, using the array length like that is clever; I haven't seen that one before.

Comment: @user124784: It's just a matter of adding another pattern to the macro, which I've added in my answer (it's much simpler since we don't need to validate the width of rows).

Comment: @FrancisGagné That's awesome! I don't think I need to worry about the user exceeding the 64 element count limit.

Answer (score 2):

### Update: there's a new way of doing things

> As of the day on which this was written, the feature of rust which enables the following (`count`) to be done, in still `unstable` and is available in `nightly` builds.
> You can check out the github [issues](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/83527) and [test cases](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/95764/files) for further understanding of what's given below

To enable this feature, you need to add the line **`#![feature(macro_metavar_expr)]`** to the top of the crate's root module (usually `main.rs` or `lib.rs`), and also set your repo to use nightly builds, which is easily done by creating a file `rust-toolchain.toml` in the root directory (alongside `Cargo.toml`) and add the folllowing lines to it:

```ini
[toolchain]
channel = "nightly"
```

> Now, instead of providing a solution to you specific problem, I'd like to share a generic solution I created to better illustrate most situations.
> I **highly** recommend studying the code **AND the comments**, by pasting the following two code blocks in a file (`main.rs`).

### The `macro_rules`

````rust
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug, Copy, Clone)]
struct SumLen {
    sum: i32,
    len: u32
}

/// currently one `i32` type is available
///
/// # Examples
///
/// The output of the following:
/// ```ignore
/// sumnarr!(i32 => 5 ; 6, 7, 8)
/// ```
/// will be `[(5, 1), (21, 3)]`
macro_rules! sumnarr {
    ( $type:ty => $( $( $x: expr ),* );* ) => {
        {
            // `${count(x,0)}` will give you "length" (number of iterations)
            // in `$( )*` loop that you are IMMEDIATELY OUTSIDE OF (e.g.: the `$( )*` loop below)

            // `${count(x,1)}` will give you TOTAL number of iterations that the `$( )*` loop
            // INSIDE of the IMMEDIATE `$( )*` loop will make. i.e. it is similar to converting
            // [ [i1,i2], [i1,i2,i3] ] TO [ i1,i2,i3,i4,i5 ] i.e. flatten the nested iteration.

            // In case of `[ [i1,i2], [i1,i2,i3] ]`, `${count(x,0)}` is 2 and `${count(x,1)}` is 5

            let mut arr: [SumLen; ${count(x,0)}] = [SumLen{ sum:0, len:0}; ${count(x,0)}];
            $(
                // `${index()}` refers to the iteration number within the `$( )*` loop
                arr[${index()}] = {

                    let mut sum = 0;
                    //let mut len = 0;

                    // THe following will give us length is the loop it is IMMEDIATELY OUTSIDE OF
                    // (the one just below)
                    let len = ${count(x,0)};

                    $(
                        sum += $x;

                        // If you were NOT using `$x` somewhere else inside `$(  )*`,
                        // then you should use `${ignore(x)};` to inform the compiler

                        //You could use the below method, where `${length()}` will give you
                        //"length" or "number of iterations" in current loop that you are in
                        // OR
                        // you could go with my method of `${count(x,0)}` which is explained above

                        //len = ${length()};
                    )*
                    SumLen {
                        sum,
                        len
                    }
                };
            )*
            arr
        }
    };
}
````

### The `#[test]` (unit test)

```rust
#[test]
fn sumnarr_macro() {
    let (a, b, c, d, e) = (4, 5, 6, 9, 10);
    let sum_lens = [
        SumLen {
            sum: a + e,
            len: 2
        },
        SumLen {
            sum: b + c + d,
            len: 3
        }
    ];
    assert_eq!(sum_lens, sumnarr!(i32 => a,e;b,c,d));
}
```

**I hope this helps**